# How do I find out where a compiler error involving macros originates?

Tags: compiler-errors, macros, rust

When I compile code that contains an error, the compiler doesn't point me to the actual line that I made error in. This happens when I use macros, e.g. `try!`.

This is an example error:

```
<std macros>:5:8: 6:45 error: mismatched types [E0308]
<std macros>:5 return $ crate :: result :: Result :: Err (
                      ^
<std macros>:5:8: 6:45 note: in this expansion of try! (defined in <std macros>)
<std macros>:5:8: 6:45 help: run `rustc --explain E0308` to see a detailed explanation
<std macros>:5:8: 6:45 note: expected type `std::path::PathBuf`
<std macros>:5:8: 6:45 note:    found type `std::result::Result<_, _>`
```

I would expect `rustc` to point me to line in file that I actually edited that causes the error but instead I only see lines from `std::macros`.

Is there a way to find out where the problem originates or should I just comment and uncomment all lines that are possible candidates?

### Edit

The general problem looks more or less like this

```
use std::result::Result;
use std::path::PathBuf;

fn get_destination_path() -> PathBuf {
   PathBuf::from(try!(get_res()))
}

fn get_res() -> Result<String, String> {
  Ok("a".to_string())
}
```

I declared `get_destination_path` as returning `PathBuf` instead of  `Result<PathBuf, String>` and that causes the error.

I found that this happens only when I use nigtly version of `rustc` (I executed `multirust override nightly` in my cargo project directory)

When I use regular rust I get much nicer error

```
error: main function not found
<std macros>:5:8: 6:42 error: mismatched types:
 expected `std::path::PathBuf`,
found `core::result::Result<_, _>`
(expected struct `std::path::PathBuf`,
found enum `core::result::Result`) [E0308]
<std macros>:5 return $ crate:: result:: Result:: Err (
<std macros>:6 $ crate:: convert:: From:: from ( err ) ) } } )
src/main.rs:6:18: 6:33 note: in this expansion of try! (defined in <std macros>)
```

So this happens on `rustc 1.10.0-nightly (d91f8ab0f 2016-05-07)` and is likely to be just a bug.

Comment: You should probably produce a [MCVE](/help/mcve) and then [file an issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues). When I compile [code that produces a similar error](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=78da72deb2690a3166bea3dd4f3735d9&version=stable&backtrace=0) I get an error that points directly to the line in question: `<anon>:4:5: 4:25 note: in this expansion of try!` (the `<anon>:4:5` bit; "anon" because I used the Playground). Maybe also [edit] your question to include the version of Rust, in case it's relevant.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I [filed an issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/33774), I used your example as it was more concise, hope you don't mind.

Comment: No worries at all; hopefully it is fixed before 1.10 is released :-)